# PostgreSQL query with sum and condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following simplified postgresql table 'fees':

```
          Table "public.fees"
id |           datetime          | fee         
---+-----------------------------+----
1  |  2013-10-17 09:11:00.138021 | 5
2  |  2013-10-17 09:15:02.848841 | 20

4  |  2013-10-18 09:17:40.784396 | 40
5  |  2013-10-18 09:29:21.789913 | 10
16 |  2013-10-18 09:39:38.308201 | 10

17 |  2013-10-19 09:40:09.507662 | 10
18 |  2013-10-19 09:40:14.310772 | 10

22 |  2013-10-20 09:54:37.183343 | 40

35 |  2013-10-21 10:32:28.619779 | 10
39 |  2013-10-21 10:34:50.830838 | 10
```

I want a sql result like this:

```
|   datetime   | feeSum                  
---------------+----
|  2013-10-17  | 25    
|  2013-10-18  | 60    
|  2013-10-19  | 20   
|  2013-10-20  | 40    
|  2013-10-21  | 20
```

which sums each day's fee to feeSum.

I've searched a lot and try this:

```
create view temp as
select datetime, fee  from fees
where
datetime::date>='2013-10-17' and
datetime::date<='2013-10-21';


do $$
    declare
        fromdate date := '2013-10-17';
        todate date := '2013-10-21';
    begin
        for d in fromdate..todate
        loop
            select sum(fee) as feeSum, d as datetime from temp
            where
            datetime::date=d;
        end loop;
    end;
$$;
```

but got error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "2013-10-17"
```

and I can't find how to define date variable. Or is there another way to get my result?

Comment: I would use the [date_trunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) function `date_trunc('day', datetime) as date`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `where
datetime::date>='2013-10-17' and
datetime::date<='2013-10-21';` no error. `fromdate date := '2013-10-17';` here cause error

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I had tried, still the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally write date constants with a date cast:

```
DATE'2013-10-17' or '2013-10-17'::date
```

Which will address your syntax error.

As for your query, you can eliminate the procedure and query it directly:

```
  SELECT datetime::date AS datetime,
         SUM(fee) AS feeSum
    FROM fees
   WHERE datetime::date BETWEEN '2013-10-17' AND '2013-10-21'
GROUP BY datetime::date
```

As people pointed out in comments, Postgres will do an implicit cast in the WHERE clause to a date type.  I tend to make the cast explicit, but I am not sure which systems would require it.

Comment: I'm a bit ignorant about PosgreSQL so I have a couple of questions. 1) Would it be the same in terms of performance to use `date(datetime)` instead of the casting? 2) Do you need to cast the string in the `where` clause or will the parser infer it as a date? 3) In case you don't need the previous cast would it be the same in terms of performance? 4) If you had written `datetime::date AS blah` and then grouped by `blah` would it have been faster?

Comment: Yeah. Your directly query works good.  For your question: 2)yes, I need to use `datetime::date` to cast timestamp to date; 4)I don't know, I'll try later.

Comment: In `where` clause, postgres don't need to cast `'2013-10-17' to '2013-10-17'::date`. While, in `declare` clause, even you cast '2013-10-17', error still there. I've made a mistake, the reason why I cast `datetime to datetime::date` is at the begining I made an equal statement. If use between, there is no need to cast `datetime`. Sorry for confusing.